# How can we get the new records created every hour without writing batch apex

Tags: integration

I have a requirement.  Every hour, I have to send new records created in Salesforce to another database.

Is there is any way to work around with formula?
Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas are not meant for doing batch processes. You can try outbound messaging tied up with a workflow. But again this works per each record. There are dozens of ETL tools available in market like

> Informatica,  Jitterbit,  Talend, mulesoft, boomi, ..

All of them are came as community edition which you can use without cost provided it has basic features supported. Using them you can create jobs, tasks which you can schedule it for hourly basis or whatever you want based on your needs.

Comment: Another one not listed that you can use as well is DBAmp.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is the simplest way to move data from salesforce to an another system.

**Replication of your salesforce data into an external system periodically can be done using Replication API**.

The Replication API is the most reliable method for data replication. It includes two functions, getUpdated and getDeleted; the former describes newly created and updated records, while the latter indicates records that have been deleted. You can use this API to accurately replicate data in your remote system without worrying about determining specific queries. Once you have a list of ID values, you can use retrieve to quickly export the data in batches of up to 2000 records. The replication API has a specific advantage that it is designed to make sure you can't miss records and won't retrieve duplicates, both of which are possible when directly querying based on CreatedDate/LastModifiedDate fields (because of in-flight transactions that won't appear in queries until they are fully committed).